# Prolog -> I have a list [X,...,Y,...Z], how do I get a list that goes only from X to Y?

Tags: prolog

SWI-PROLOG.
I have a list [X, ..., Y, ..., Z], how do I get a list that goes only from X to Y?
That is [**X, ..., Y**, ..., Z] --> **[X, ..., Y]**.
I have little to none knowledge on this language, so all help is welcome!
I tried this:

```
bla([Ele|_], Ele, _). 
bla([H|T], Ele, Res):-
   append(Res, H, New_Res),
   bla([T], Ele, New_Res).
```

Here, `Ele` would be the Y.
And I initialized what would be `Res` as an empty list.

I repeat, I'm new to this language, so what I wrote might be very wrong, sorry!

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? What if you have, `[X, ..., Y, ..., Y, ... Z]`? Do you want up to the first `Y` or the last `Y`? Or do you want each as a possible solution?

Comment: @lurker it's something I needed for a uni assignment. It's just a small part of the big problem. And the elements of the list are not repeated, so only one Y.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`append/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) it may be just:

```
bla(L, Ele, NL):-
  append(NL1, [Ele|_], L),
  append(NL1, [Ele], NL).
```

Noting that `append(L1,L2,L3)` succeeds when L3 is the concatenation of L1 and L2 you can extract the items from L up to a desired item with the first append (`append(NL1, [Ele|_], L)`), where in this example L2 is a list that starts with element `Ele`, therfore L is a list that starts with NL1 and for which the next element of L is Ele.

The second append is used to add Ele to the end of NL1.

Without using `append/3` you may write:

```
bla([Ele|_], Ele, [Ele]).
bla([E|L], Ele, [E|NL]):-
  bla(L, Ele, NL).
```

Both implementation may succeed more than once if Ele appears more than once in L and will fail if Ele does not appear in L.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!
Could you explain how the first one works though?

Comment: @TomásGomes: added some explanation to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, since your predicate is describing a relation between two lists and a pivot element, you could opt to use DCGs for the task:

```
list_pivot_sublist(L,P,S) :-
   phrase(sublist_till(L,P),S).  % the sublist up to the pivot element
                                 % is described by the DCG sublist_till//2

sublist_till([P|_],P) -->        % if the head of the list is P
   [P].                          % it's the last element in the sublist
sublist_till([X|Xs],P) -->       % if the head of the list is any element X
   [X],                          % X is in the sublist and
   sublist_till(Xs,P).           % the same goes for the tail and P
```

Now let's see some queries:

*What's the sublist of [1,2,3,4,5] up to the element 3?*

```
?- list_pivot_sublist([1,2,3,4,5],3,S).
S = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

*Which sublist-pivot pairs are there for [1,2,3,4,5]?*

```
?- list_pivot_sublist([1,2,3,4,5],P,S).
P = 1,
S = [1] ;
P = 2,
S = [1, 2] ;
P = 3,
S = [1, 2, 3] ;
P = 4,
S = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
P = 5,
S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ;
false.
```

*What could the original list and a fitting pivot element look like for the sublist [1,2,3]?*

```
?- list_pivot_sublist(L,P,[1,2,3]).
L = [1, 2, 3|_G4751],
P = 3 ;
false.
```

Or the most general query: *What corresponding list, pivot elements and sublists are there?*

```
?- list_pivot_sublist(L,P,S).
L = [P|_G4739],
S = [P] ;
L = [_G4738, P|_G4745],
S = [_G4738, P] ;
L = [_G4738, _G4744, P|_G4751],
S = [_G4738, _G4744, P] ;
L = [_G4738, _G4744, _G4750, P|_G4757],
S = [_G4738, _G4744, _G4750, P] ;
.
.
.
```

These are the same answers that you get with @gusbro's versions of `bla/3`, with the exception of this query...

```
?- bla(L,P,[1,2,3]).
L = [1, 2, 3|_G4739],
P = 3 ;

ERROR: Out of global stack
```

... that loops with the first version (the one with two `append/3` as goals) after delivering the only answer. The reason for this is that the first goal delivers infinitely many solution candidates...

```
?- append(NL1, [Ele|_], L).
NL1 = [],
L = [Ele|_G900] ;
NL1 = [_G1000],
L = [_G1000, Ele|_G900] ;
NL1 = [_G1000, _G1006],                                   % this candidate leads to
L = [_G1000, _G1006, Ele|_G900] ;                         % the only solution
NL1 = [_G1000, _G1006, _G1012],
L = [_G1000, _G1006, _G1012, Ele|_G900] ;
.
.
.
```

... all of which fail except for the one marked in the query above:

```
?- append(NL1, [Ele|_], L), append(NL1, [Ele], [1,2,3]).
NL1 = [1, 2],                                             % corresponding answer
Ele = 3,                                                  % to the third candidate
L = [1, 2, 3|_G4641] ;                                    % above
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

Hence, the non-`append/3` version is clearly preferable. With reference to the comment by @lurker, I'd also like to note that, with these versions, you'll get multiple answers, if the pivot element occurs more than once in the list:

```
?- list_pivot_sublist([1,2,3,4,5,3],3,S).
S = [1, 2, 3] ;
S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3] ;
```

If you only want to get the first sublist, you can alter the DCG-version by adding a constraint, `X` differs from `P`, that prevents Prolog from further recursions after the first success:

```
sublist_till([P|_],P) -->
   [P].
sublist_till([X|Xs],P) -->
   {dif(X,P)},                % <- new constraint
   [X],
   sublist_till(Xs,P).
```

Now the above query yields only one answer:

```
?- list_pivot_sublist([1,2,3,4,5,3],3,S).
S = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

The most general query also slightly differs, since now it propagates the `dif/2` constraints up to the answer:

```
?- list_pivot_sublist(L,P,S).
L = [P|_G4739],
S = [P] ;
L = [_G4886, P|_G4890],
S = [_G4886, P],
dif(_G4886, P) ;
L = [_G4942, _G4945, P|_G4949],
S = [_G4942, _G4945, P],
dif(_G4942, P),
dif(_G4945, P) ;
.
.
.
```

You can alter @gusbro's second version to sport the same behaviour by adding the same constraint to the recursive rule:

```
bla([Ele|_], Ele, [Ele]).
bla([E|L], Ele, [E|NL]):-
  dif(E,Ele),                  % <- new constraint
  bla(L, Ele, NL).
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `append/3` give already what you want?

```
?- append(L, [y|_], [x,x,x,y,x,y,x,z]).
L = [x, x, x] ;
L = [x, x, x, y, x] ;
false.
```

You can re-add the last 'y' element with another call to `append/3`:

```
?- append(L, [y|_], [x,x,x,y,x,y,x,z]), append(L, [y], L1).
L1 = [x, x, x, y] ;
L1 = [x, x, x, y, x, y] ;
false.
```